# Removing item from listbox

Tags: vb.net

I have a form that has 9 texbox that when I click on a certain button it adds whatever is in it to a listbox, I also have a remove button that removes an item from listbox, is there a way I can remove the item and clear the textbox it came from?

Answer (score 0):

Remove item from ListBox:

```
ListBox1.Items.Remove(sItemtext)
ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(indexItem)
```

Clear the TextBox:

```
TextBox1.Text = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
Public Class Form1
Dim oLB As TextBox
Dim aList As New List(Of TextBox)

Sub GetLB(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus, TextBox2.GotFocus, TextBox3.GotFocus
    oLB = CType(sender, TextBox)
End Sub

Private Sub btnMoveToList_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMoveToList.Click
    ListBox1.Items.Add(oLB.Text)
    aList.Add(oLB)
End Sub

Private Sub btnRemoveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveItem.Click
    Dim n As Integer = ListBox1.SelectedIndex

    aList(n).Text = ""
    ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n)
    aList.RemoveAt(n)
End Sub
End Class
```